# getting the value of a hidden input

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have this code:

```
<div id = "askpost" class="row">
<input type="hidden" name="askid" id="askid" value="<?php echo $askpostid ?>">
</div>
```

and i want to get the id of the hidden input but when tried using this:

```
  <script>
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('input[name="iaskcomment"]').on('keyup', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var comment = $(this).val();
      var ask_id = $(this).siblings('.askid').val();

      alert(ask_id); <----undefined
  });
}); 

</script>
```

i even used this code :

```
var sid = $(this).closest("div#askpost").find("input[type='hidden']").val();
```

but also i get "undefined". what i wanted to do is to get the id of $askpostid

Comment: what about $("#askid").val() ?

Comment: `$('#askid').val();` if this has ID use it . but it should be unique. assuming you have many of this you need to use class but you need to share the mark up for use to identify the relation ship between the input and the hidden input

Comment: anyway it's not the sibling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

direct use `$("#askid").val()`. No need to use anything like `siblings()`

Example:-

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[name="iaskcomment"]').on('keyup', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var comment = $(this).val();
    var ask_id = $('#askid').val();
     alert(ask_id);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id = "askpost" class="row">
<input name = "iaskcomment"><br>
<input type="hidden" name="askid" id="askid" value="2">
</div>
```

***Note:- Your code doesn't have any input with name `iaskcomment`. I have added in my example to just show you how it will work.So check at your end.***

Comment: also they are not siblings because in mark up hidden input is solo in div

Comment: Alfie Garing  glad to help you.:):)